# Convert table of hashes to straight columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, formatting, html-table

My view generates a table that looks something like this:

7days ::::: 30days :::: 90days
[1, 2, 5, 6] [2, 5, 6, 7] [4, 6, 7, 6]

Instead I would like a table that looks like:

7days : 30days : 90days
1 :::::::::2 ::::::::::: 4
5 :::::::::5 ::::::::::: 6
1 :::::::::6 ::::::::::: 7

I'm not sure how to turn the hashes into columns.

controller

```
@daysvals = Dcomet.group(:site).sum(:ls7day),
Dcomet.group(:site).sum(:gt7day),
Dcomet.group(:site).sum(:gt30day),
Dcomet.group(:site).sum(:gt90day),
Dcomet.group(:site).sum(:gt180day),
Dcomet.group(:site).sum(:gt365day)
```

view.html.erb

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><h4>&lt;7days</h4></td>
<td><h4>&gt;7days</h4></td>
<td><h4>&gt;30days</h4></td>
<td><h4>&gt;90days</h4></td>
<td><h4>&gt;180days</h4></td>
<td><h4>&gt;365days</h4></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<% @daysvals.each do |test| %>
  <td><%= test.values%></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
</table>
```

Dcomet model

```
class Dcomet < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :site, :case_id, :created_date, :ls7day, :gt7day, :gt30day, :gt90day, :gt180day, :gt365day, :hours_open
end
```

Comment: You're not getting answers because it's impossible to give you correct code without seeing the `Dcomet` model, i.e. what `group` and `sum` are doing.

Comment: i added dcomet.rb model.

Comment: im grouping my data by the building location, and then suming the data that is grouped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting up `@dayvals` as a list of hashes  Your view must expand the other list into table rows and each inner list into row items.  This will be close.  In the controller, transpose to get the table rows:

```
cols = [:ls7day, :gt7day, :gt30day, :gt90day, :gt180day, :gt365day]

# Make per-group ordered hashes of sums.
@daysvals = cols.map {|c| Dcomet.group(:site).sum(c)}

# Make a table where each hash's value sequence is a column.
@daystable = @daysvals.map{|hash| hash.values}.transpose
```

In the view, emit one row per list element

```
<% @daystable.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
  <% row.each do |item| %>
    <td><%= item %></td>
  <% end %> 
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: oh one more thing. could i make the first column "keys"?

That way it shows which :site each row belongs to?

Comment: Try replacing the last controller line with `@daystable = @daysvals.map{|hash| hash.values}.unshift(@daysvals[0].keys).transpose`